# /etc/bind/rrset-order: order 'fixed' was disabled at compilation time

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, bind

How do I recompile bind9 so that I can enable rrset-order fixed?

```
/etc/bind/named.conf.options:9: rrset-order: order 'fixed' was disabled at compilation time
```

My OS is Ubuntu 20.04

[It](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-server-bugs/2009-July/014825.html) said I need rebuit it with `--enable-fixed-rrset` flag

But where should I execute it?

Comment: I know my answer might not suit your question, but as DevOps guy with 13 years of work experience and working with a large number of DNS servers with high load, I am not recommending compiling bind and using it. in production, there is a huge difference in the performance for the complied version vs binary version. complied version perfomance is awful

Comment: Then where I can get binary version with ```--enable-fixed-rrset```

Comment: my suggestion is to use FreeBSD OS for this case, by this you can use ports to install Bind. although installing a package with ports, still compiles the source. but there is a huge difference when compiling the source via ports in FreeBSD vs Linux.